# Example of Subscription class using Graphene and Python

Tags: python, publish-subscribe, graphql, graphene-python, graphql-subscriptions

I trying to figure out how to correctly define subscriptions in my schema using graphene-python. So far I have implemented queries and mutations, but how do you define a `Subscription` class?

Below is what I was originally thinking:

```
class Subscription(graphene.Subscription):
  name = graphene.String()
  # rest of attributes...

  def subscribe(self, args, context, info):
    pass
```

Can someone please provide a small example? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you :).

Brian

Comment: I believe I have figured it out. Once I am comfortable with the code, I will post back here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some trial and error, the following code below will work for subscriptions. Essentially a subscription can be treated the same as a query.

```
class Subscription(graphene.ObjectType):
  # Define subscription attributes, i.e. what you want the user to subscribe to.
  # This part will most likely be defined by your schema.
  subscription_attr = graphene.Int()

  def resolve_events_count(self, args, context, info):
    ## define resolver function once UI provides subscription data...
    return 'Value here defined as graphene class'
```